# How to create a GMT field from time zone datetime field

Tags: lotusscript

My ultimate goal is to get the time difference between 2 date/time fields.  The rub is that one field, say the Create field, is time stamped in the US Eastern time zone.  The 'Closed' field (hours later) is timestamped in, say, Sidney, Australia, with it's time zone .  How many hours between these 2 times?  (And no jokes about Relativity! ;-)).  So my thought was to convert both times to GMT and then do a NotesDateTime.TimeDifference.  However, I can't seem to convert these field to GMT.  I was able to create a 3rd date/time field using the Create fields's LSGMTTime.  But all that did was to create a new NotesDateTime field with the correct GMT time but with the timezone of US Eastern time.  Maybe that would work in the long run since the subtraction is unitless.  But it would be nice to get a couple of pure GMT time fields.  Or maybe there's some other way of doing this.  Thoughts?

Thanks
Clem

Comment: I don't really understand your request: Date / Time- Fields normally have their timezone information stored and subtracting two fields is as Simple as doc.FirstDate - doc.SecondDate without having to take care for timezones at all...

Comment: @TorstenLink.  After doing some testing, I see that you're correct.  I didn't realize the NotesDateTime.TimeDifference takes time zones into account and thought I'd have to do that myself before doing the subtraction.  Thanks.  Clem